# SAPI-XML ignoring tags (volume, voice)

Tags: sapi

I had SAPI up and running for quite some time and worked quite well. At some point (well after upgrade to Win11) it stopped working, and throwing errors. Currently I got it back up to speak, but it is ignoring all tags. I use it in delphi, but now work with powershell to test stuff.
My code is simple:

```
$Vol=1
$T="This is a test."
$PromptTTS.Speak('<speak version="1.0" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US"><voice required="Gender=Male" xml:lang="en-US"><lang langid="409" xml:lang="en-US"><volume level="'+$Vol+'" xml:lang="en-US">'+$T+'</volume></lang></voice></speak>')
```

It is saying "This is a test" but completely ignoring the volume and the voice is female. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

$PromptTTS has a property called volume, which IS working. Just not the tag!

$PromptTTS.Volume:=5 does the trick